# Populate a Prototype Cell by Passing Object

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView that is using prototype cells (everything in storyboard). Ideally, I would like to pass these cells an object via the cellForRowAtIndexPath and have the cell figure out how to populate it's labels etc...

setSelected seems to work, but only if the cells are not scrolled off screen. Once they are scrolled off the screen much of the cell's logic is broken. See sample code for the current approach:

```
class RequirementsAndContentsCell: UITableViewCell {

    var represents = String()
    var item = PLItem()
    var requirement = PLCaseRequirement()
    var content = PLCaseContent()

    @IBOutlet weak var itemNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var barcodeIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var barcodeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainLabelVerticalAlign: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var barcodeIconLeadingSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagViewLeadingSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!


    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        tagView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        if represents == "content" {
            itemNameLabel.text = content.name
            unitCountLabel.attributedText = createAttributedString("\(content.qty)", "\nUnits", "HelveticaNeue-Light", 12, UIColor.darkTextColor())
            barcodeLabel.text = content.barcode
            statusView.hidden = true
            if content.isParent == true {
                tagView.hidden = true
                tagViewLeadingSpace.priority = 1
            }
        } else if represents == "requirement" {
            itemNameLabel.text = requirement.name
            mainLabelVerticalAlign.constant = 0
            tagView.hidden = true
            barcodeIcon.hidden = true
            barcodeLabel.hidden = true
            unitCountLabel.attributedText = createAttributedString("\(requirement.qty)", "\nUnits", "HelveticaNeue-Light", 12, UIColor.darkTextColor())
            if item.isContainer == true {
                updateStatusView()
            } else {
                statusView.hidden = true
            }

        }


    }



    func updateStatusView () {
        if requirement.fulfillmentLevel == 0 {
            statusView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        } else if requirement.fulfillmentLevel == 1 {
            statusView.layer.backgroundColor = GlobalVars.yellowColor.CGColor
        } else if requirement.fulfillmentLevel == 2 {
            statusView.layer.backgroundColor = GlobalVars.goodColor.CGColor
        } else {
            statusView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
        }
    }

}
```

What is the proper way of achieving the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to populate the cell in `setSelected`. Create a method that takes the object you're tying to pass as an argument, and call that from cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `UITableViewDelegate`'s function `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` so that you can update the view of the cell when it's about to be displayed.